# Forcing Base 10's working improperly in BASH

Tags: linux, bash

So I found out the hard way that `$(date +%H)` will return a base 8 number from 1 am to 9 am. No big deal, I forced it to be a base 10 number by writing: `$((10#$(date +%H) ))`... Here is my issue, writing exactly that throws an error "-bash: 9: command not found" but if I say `echo $((10#$(date +%H) ))` it will return me the proper number. Any clue to why this happens? And how will you go about fixing it? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your variant of `date` is fairly recent, there are format modifiers that can change or disable the padding as per the `man` page:

---

By default, `date` pads numeric fields with zeroes.  The following optional flags may follow `%`:

- `-` (hyphen) do not pad the field.
- `_` (underscore) pad with spaces.
- `0` (zero) pad with zeros.

---

Hence the *first* thing I would try would be `date -%-H`. This should give you the hour without any padding.

On the off chance you have an ancient `date` variant, you can get an actual *number* (single or double digit depending on the time) with something like:

```
((hr = 1$(date +%H) - 100))
```

The `1$(date +%H)` will give you a value between `100` and `123` inclusive then subtract `100` to give you the numeric hour.

For example, at 4:23am, this will take the `04` from `date +%H`, turn that into `104` then subtract `100` to get the number `4`.

Numbers greater than `9` will also work. The time 4:42pm will take the `16` from `date +%H`, turn that into `116` then subtract `100` to get the number `16`.

---

In respect to why you're getting an error, the command `$((10#$(date +%H)))` will evaluate to `9` (assuming time is `09:xx`) and then just try to execute that (which, unless you have an executable `9` somewhere in you path, will error).

Prefixing it with `echo` will cause the command `echo 9` to be run, which *is* valid.

As you can see, you don't need to echo it, you can store it in a variable (like `hr` above) for later use.

Comment: Can you explain what actually happens within the script?

Comment: @ConfuzzledandPuzzled, hopefully the update will leave you less confuzzled and/or puzzled :-)

Comment: Thank you so much, but do you know why excluding echo in the script in my question throws an error, whereas adding it lets it run properly?

Comment: Just use "date +%k" if you don't want the leading zero.

Comment: @Wayne, that may introduce yet *other* problems since it space pads on the left: `%k hour, space padded ( 0..23); same as %_H`

Comment: @paxdiablo, true, but that is easy enough to deal with. Need to see more of what he is actually trying to do to determine that.

Comment: As it turns out, `date` can remove the padding altogether - see the update.